# Can not inflate button widget after/before GridView

Tags: android

I want to add a button widget just above the GridView,But it seems not happy with my code, i mean its not showing up on the screen, no matter what i am doing,by the way am on 7.1.1, here is my layout,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/images_grid_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:columnWidth="180dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="8dp">

    </GridView>
      <Button
        android:text="Next"
        android:id="@+id/next_Button"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

      </LinearLayout>
```

So this is it, layout is insanely simple, but i can not figure it out, any help would be highly appreciable !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Next" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/images_grid_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/next_Button"
        android:columnWidth="180dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="8dp">

    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Use `RelativeLayout` to let the `Button` stick to the parent's bottom, and set the `GridView` to stay above the button

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use Linear layout weight attribute.If you are trying to use it grid layout layout height attribute should also be 0dp and you should add layout weight attribute for grid layout too.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <GridView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/images_grid_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="6"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:columnWidth="180dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="8dp">

        </GridView>
          <Button
            android:text="Next"
            android:id="@+id/next_Button"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />

          </LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps u.

Comment: Thanks ! You saved the day !

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote brother ! 